# How to use bind parameters in sequelize without query builder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

every I use this query in sequelize:

```
await Sequelize.findAll({
  where: {
   status: '$open'
 },
 bind: {
   open: 'open'
 }
})
```

The query executed like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status='?'
```

And data is not returned

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use bind params when the query is not a raw query.

```js
const open = 'open'

await Model.findAll({
  where: {
   status: open
 },
})
```

If you are using a raw query, then you may want to use `replacements` attribute:

```js
await Model.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE status=:status', { replacements: {
     status: 'open',
  }
})
```

Comment: What if I'm trying to prevent values in WHERE clause from being logged ?

Comment: you can set a custom `logging`mechanism, which you can log the query in any format. You can set any logic here, e.g., to hide the "where" values.

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/#logging